# Problema con imagen de fondo en aplicación web

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

Estoy  trabaja con cordova en una pequeña App:

```css
body {
  background: url("https://lorempixel.com/505/500/cats/1");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 505px 500px;
  background-color: #40B3CD;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

En un navegador se ve así:

[image: Imagen de fondo en un navegador]

Cuando genero la apk y la ejecuto en el celular, se ve así:

[image: Imagen de fondo en un celular]

¿Es posible poner el fondo con una imagen que se adapte?

Comment: acepta el comentario de un novato y espero no liarte más. Tu problema principal creo que radica en el tamaño de la imagen. En el background-size: tienes puesto un tamaño en pixeles que probablemente sea mayor que el de tu dispositivo móvil, por eso se ve la imagen aumentada al abrirla desde ahí y más reducida cuando la ves desde la pantalla de tu ordenador (ya que tiene una resolución mayor a 500px). Te recomiendo que aprendas a implementar las media query en css. Un saludo.

Comment: como ya te dijeron en el comentario anterior, tienes las dimensiones en pixeles y alli ya limitas la adaptación de esta, lo otro sería trabajar con media querys que adapten la imagen a las resoluciones mas apropiadas. Por otro lado, si quieres que se adapta simplemente ponla como `baclground-size:cover` esto automaticamente rellenara el total de la pantalla con la imagen, tambien te sugiero que cuides el aspect ratio de la imagen, ya que estas usando una imagen a 4:3 y por ende se verá un poco gigante en pantallas que no manejan ese estandar como los moviles.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
    <style>

    body {
        background-image: url('http://jsequeiros.com/sites/default/files/imagen-cachorro-comprimir.jpg');
        background-color: #40B3CD;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

  </style>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: y esto que mejora o como puede ayudar a resolver lo que pregunta el OP.?

Comment: Si miras el ejemplo en un html la imagen se comporta de manera responsive. Le digo que lo pruebe a ver si se ve bien.